# How to smoothen jquery slider?

Tags: jquery, slider

i have this jquery slider code here -
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9V7W/) or [jquery demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/side-scroll.html)
now all i want to do is that i want to make the slider work more smoother
please help!

P.S. by smoother i mean that i drag the slider to a little distance from my mouse and it automatically gets dragged to a little more...its an animation affect kind of something.....and i tried those options on the demo page but they just make the slider disappear and not function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 slide: function(event, ui) {
            if (scrollContent.width() > scrollPane.width()) {
                scrollContent.animate({
                    "margin-left": Math.round(ui.value / 100 * (scrollPane.width() - scrollContent.width()))
                }, 20);

            } else {
                scrollContent.animate({
                    "margin-left": 0
                }, 20);
            }
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v9V7W/3/

Comment: now that was something i was really searching for!!!...i tried to put the animate option but it didn't work...thanks a lot for helping...

Answer (score 0):

What is your view on the word 'smoother'? jQuery slider has numerous options that can influence the behavior of it (http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/), so try to expiriment with that.

Comment: by smoother i mean that i drag the slider to a little distance from my mouse and it automatically gets dragged to a little more...its an animation affect kind of something.....and i tried those options on the demo page but they just make the slider disappear and not function.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually made one which we currently use at work. You can use CSS3 property of transform3d to make a smooth slide.  Transform3d is hardware accelerated, unlike margin-left or left, so it's a lot smoother.

You can check it out here - http://dezignhero.github.io/swiper/

It's designed primarily for webkit devices but also works on desktop too.